# I found a bug in my interpreter that terminates the program if the input has new lines. How do I make the program ignore such inputs?

Tags: c#, interpreter

Last night I built my very first interpreter, a BrainFuck interpreter written in C#.
It seemed to work well, until I noticed that it can only take one liners, input such as new lines doesn't get recognized by the program as a suitable input, so it terminates after the first line, as in I paste in 3 lines, it only pastes in the first line and exits with code 0.

I've tried some different approaches such as the Replace() function, but so far no luck, and other related questions' solutions didn't solve it either.

```cs
    public class Interpreter
    {
        private byte[] stack;
        private int ptr;
        private char[] input;

        public Interpreter(string input)
        {
           
            this.input = input.ToCharArray();
            stack = new byte[65535];
        }
```

The issue lies with `this.input = input.ToCharArray();`.

If I could get some help with figuring out how to fix this bug, I'd really appreciate it. Note that I'm also not a very experienced programmer yet, so feel free to make inputs about anything else as well if you feel the want to.

Here's the source code to the entire project in case it's needed.
https://pastebin.com/eRtHHYDD

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but the tape/memory of a BrainFuck program does not act as a stack, so naming it `tape` or `memory` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your main method, from your pastebin, is:

```cs
var Interpreter = new Interpreter(Console.ReadLine());
Interpreter.Run();
```

[`Console.ReadLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netcore-3.1#System_Console_ReadLine) consumes just the first line of input. Your program thus reads the first line, passes it to the interpreter, runs, and then exits without looking at later lines in the standard input stream.

To address this, you'll need to find a way to consume all of the input. Options I can think of, in increasing order of difficulty:

- Requiring that the input be specified in a file, not through standard input. You can then use various APIs (e.g. `System.IO.File`) to read the entire file's text.
- Looping over the standard input's lines until none are left, then combining the lines before passing it to your interpreter. If you're expecting the interpreter to take interactive human input, though, this might not be desirable, because `ReadLine` will block and wait for input if nothing was piped to the process' standard input.
- Updating your interpreter so it can take partial input, and pass each line to it as you receive it from standard input.

Comment: I feel like the second one is the most feasable for me, I'll give it a go and come back to you on how that goes.

Comment: In order to read all of stdin, you can just use `System.In.ReadToEnd()` - no need to loop line-by-line. And to terminate the input when it's not piped in, you can press Ctrl+Z (when using the Windows command prompt) or Ctrl+d (when using other terminals).